# PHP oтправить json методом POST

Tags: php, json, post

```
$user = array(
    'name'=> $user_name,
    'lastname'=> $user_lastname,
    'mail'=> $user_mail,
    'birthday'=> $user_date,
    'phone'=> $user_phone,
    'cardnumber'=> $user_cardnumb, 
);

$json[] = $user;
$json = json_encode($json);

$ch = curl_init('адрес');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Есть url сервера, логин и пароль. Как сделать с помощью curl? Не могу разобраться.

Comment: А что конкретно не получается ? есть ли ошибки от CRON ?

Comment: var_dump($response) выводит: string(269) "
1C:Enterprise 8 application error:

РќРµРєРѕСЂСЂРµРєС‚РЅС‹Рµ СЃРёРјРІРѕР»С‹ РІ Р·Р°РіРѕР»РѕРІРєРµ HTTP: [
Content-Length: 0]"

Comment: Некорректные символы в заголовке HTTP

Comment: Куда смотреть? Где ошибся?

Comment: в первую очередь используйте  CURL error handle, http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php , может будет более понятная ошибка

Comment: if(curl_exec($ch) === false){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
   }else{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   echo "<pre>";var_dump($ch);echo "</pre>";die();

Comment: вернуло Operation completed without any errors
resource(2) of type (Unknown)
Значит ли это что всё прошло нормально?

Comment: Всё-таки выдает "Operation completed without any errors
string(269) "
1C:Enterprise 8 application error:

Некорректные символы в заголовке HTTP: [
Content-Length: 0]""

Comment: Вопрос актуален.

Comment: Трудно угадать в чём проблема, т.к  могут быть очень много причин. Думаю проблема в вашем CURL запросе, создайте новый запро используя вот это http://webmasterschool.ru/notes/note12.php, там есть пример POST

Comment: Скорее всего из-за того, что
 $in = file_get_contents('php://input');
   echo $in . "\n";
   print_r(json_decode($in, true)); 
выдает:
 user_name=%C8%E2%E0%ED&user_last_name=test&user_mail=test&user_date=2017.11.04&user_phone=89087654321&user_cardnumb=763456391930950&createcard=createcard
Как исправить? И почему все данные идут, а не только то, что лежит в json?